# JSTL Choose tag always evaluating to false

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, jsp-fragments

```
<%
    Boolean loggedIn = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("login");
    System.out.println("loggedIn is " + loggedIn);
%>

<header>
    <% System.out.println("loggedIn is now " + loggedIn); %>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${loggedIn}">
            <a href="#"> My Profile </a>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <a href="#"> Sign In </a>
        </c:otherwise>   
    </c:choose>
</header>
```

This is a JSPF for a project that I have made. The output for the following is

```
loggedIn is true
loggedIn is now true
```

Despite this, my actual page always shows "Sign in" and never shows "My Profile". Also, when I change the condition to

```
<c:when test="${not loggedIn}">
```

It begins to display "My Profile". I do not get how loggedIn can be true and yet fail this  statement.

Thankyou.

Comment: Stop using scriptlets. Really, just stop. They're a thing from the very old past. The JSP EL uses **attributes** of the page, request, session or application. Not local scriptlet variables. So it should simply be `test="${login}"` (or `test="${sessionScope.login}"`), since that's how your **attribute** is named.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah this worked. I've just started using JSP and didn't know that scriptlets were frowned upon until now. Thanks for the answer.